# File missing html

Tags: kali-linux

In Kali Linux when I go to directory /var/www/ I don't get html in it. I didn't had any idea some tutorial said it to delete so i deleted it. Can someone tell me how to recover it

Comment: This may be relevant: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5530/4778 (What kali is for, and setting up a web-browser are very different things)

Comment: Sorry but it didn't help.

Comment: You seem to lack basic knowledge of a linux system (for example that you can't 'undo' an `rm` operation). Therefore, it would probably be best for you to pick a different distro. Also, you didn't tell us any information - what webserver, how the config was set up etc.

Comment: I guess `/var/www/html` was a directory and not just a regular file. Which command did you use to delete it? Are you now missing anything out of it?

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the `/var/www/html` directory itself, it's simplest to just recreate it:

```
# mkdir /var/www/html
```

But if you want to recover the directory *and its default contents*, you'll need to find out which package the directory belongs to, and reinstall that package. On Debian it can be done like this, and I assume Kali will be similar as it is ultimately based on Debian:

```
# dpkg-query -S /var/www/html
apache2: /var/www/html
# apt reinstall apache2
```

Depending on what packages are installed on your system, it might be e.g. `nginx` instead of `apache2`.

But you should not follow any random tutorials or advice from the internet without at least trying to understand what the commands mean and verifying that the advice makes sense in your situation before you apply it.

Kali is designed for professionals who already know the basics, and so it and any documentation for it will generally just assume that the user knows how to do things like the commands above without further explanation. This is one of the things that can make Kali and its documentation especially hard to use for a beginner.